# Give every prefab his own speed

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

Is was building a star background simulation for a spaceshooter game in UNITY3D.
In c# i built The Instantitiation of prefabs which look like dots. While the generation of multiple dots on random spots on the x-axis go perfectly i wanted to add one thing.

Random speed. The problem is that i don't know how to give every prefab his own speed en keep it instead of getting overwritten by the next randomnization.

backgroundloop.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class backgroundloop : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject star;
    public float spawnTime;
    private GameObject starPrefab;
    private float timestamp;
    //public float hoogte = Random.Range(-1.01f,1.1f);
    //public float rotationPrefab = transform.localEulerAngles.z;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Time.time > timestamp)  {
            starPrefab = Instantiate 
            (star, new  Vector3(7,Random.Range(-5.0f,5.0f),0), 
            Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
            timestamp = Time.time + spawnTime;
            }   
        }
    }
```

And the problem is in this script:
prefabMovement.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class prefabMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    float speed = Random.Range (-3f, -0.1f);


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.Translate (new Vector3(-1f,0,0) * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position.x < -6.8) {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can place `Random.Range` in `void Start()` method so every instantiatd prefab will randomize its speed.

Comment: Tried that, but lots of problems:      The name `speed' does not exist in the current context,                                        The best overloaded method match for UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments        Argument #1' cannot convert object  expression to type 'float'

Comment: But there is no `speed` variable used in your `Update` method. And ofc you can create variable `float speed = 0f;` and in `Start` just set the value like `speed = Random.Range(...);`

Comment: Couldn't this be achieved a lot simpler and easier using a Particle System? You could scale it to the size of our background, and give each dot a random speed between a set of 2 ints.

Comment: True, but i want to create it this way for study reasons. I'm not looking for the easy way, but to encounter problems and try to fix them

Comment: And your fix could be: use a particle system!

Comment: Particle system is irrelevant here.  @KeyxvanLierop -- you just had a**a number of simple syntax errors**.  I gave solution below, have nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh? So the speed is overwritten and eventually ends up being the same on all instantiated prefabs?

Maybe it helps if initialize the speed variable inside the Start method.

Comment: Tried that, but lots of problems:      The name `speed' does not exist in the current context,                                        The best overloaded method match for UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments        Argument #1' cannot convert object  expression to type 'float'

Comment: Declare the speed variable inside the class `float speed;`
Initialize the speed variable inside the `Start()` method `speed = Random.Range (-3f, -0.1f);`
Then you need to use the speed variable somewhere